# Correctly traversing to the elements in the same block

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal

I would appreciate help on jQuery.
Here, everything works just fine:
[jsfiddle- this works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/UHskr/)

But here, with TWO identical HTML blocks on the same page, they clash (they interfere with each other, when you click the "show" in second block, it affects the 1st block):
[jsfiddle - the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/g6dSv/)

Is there a way to change JS (correctly use .closest(),.find(), other traversing techniques), so that I can have as many of those blocks on the same page as needed and all working independently?
(without inventing new IDs and multiplying the JS code).

I can traverse easily `<li>`'s, but is it possible with DIVs?

**EDIT:**
(I don't have reputation for anything, so using edit:
Thank you very much for help and the extra brush up on the IDs.
Everything works perfectly.

All the best)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have id duplication (turn them to classnames `.funFactAnswer`) and your selector is generic, make it more specific to the target.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".showfunFactAnswer").click(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         $this.closest('.funFactWrap').find('.funFactAnswer').slideDown()
         $this.next().removeClass("hide");
     });
     $(".hideButtonAnswer").click(function () {
         $(this).addClass("hide").closest('.funFactWrap').find('.funFactAnswer').slideUp()
     });

 });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T85mT/)**

With duplicate ids , id selectors will select only the first instance of the element with the same id.